# Overusing sitecustomize.py: .bash_profile instead?

Tags: python, django, shell, bash

Maybe it's because I am more comfortable with python over the shell, but I chose to add to my `sys.path` list in `/usr/lib/python[x.x]/sitecustomize.py` in this manner:

```
base = '/home/droogans/py/'

locs = ['foo','django']

for loc in locs:
    sys.path.insert(0, base + loc)
```

And now I've added a `try:except` block below it, in case I want to test out a template without using the `python manage.py shell` approach.

```
try:
    from django.core.management import setup_environ
    from website_foobar import settings
    setup_environ(settings)
except ImportError:
    pass
```

The DjangoBook has a section, "[A special python prompt](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter04/)", that recommends you do this, but suggests using your `.bash_profile` shell script for the task. Is there a measurable benefit to utilizing that instead of a `sitecustomize.py` script? Obviously, I'm already done, so there'll have to be some kind of compelling evidence for me to google an article on writing shell code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you are not going to have superuser status on the machine you are using. In such cases you won't be able to modify `/usr`, so it would be necessary then to know how to set environment variables in your personal ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile. (The particular file to use depends on your system).

It's not hard to do. All you'd need to add (I think!) is something like

```
PYTHONPATH=$HOME/py/foo:$HOME/py/django
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=website_foobar.settings

export PYTHONPATH DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

Comment: Hm. That looks about painless. I forgot to write out the extra step in my `sudo gedit /usr/lib/python[x.x]/...` command, a small detail that *does* kind of get on my nerves. Thanks for pointing out the difference.

Comment: So what you're saying is that a user signing into the non-credentialed "guest" account on my machine would have access to django-templates...is this something to be concerned about?

Comment: If you changed `group` and `other` `read/execute` the permissions on your django directory, then they would not be able to read your files. I think it just be an unused directory in their `sys.path`. However, it is still not the ideal way to set up a multi-user machine.

Comment: I threw it in there under `~/.bashrc` with `export PYTHONPATH=~/py/django:~/py/foo` being the only line. Best part, is it applies across my 2.6 and 3.1 python sessions. Thanks.